# What modes are used for transmitting motion pictures video?

Tags: modes, sstv, atv

SSTV permits transmission of single images, or if one desires image sequences at a very low framerate.

Are there specific Amateur Modes that are meant for real time (motion pictures) video transmission, or do amateurs simply use NTSC, PAL, or digital modes to transmit video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Amateur televison (ATV) one can transmit 800x600 pixels with 25 images ("frames") per second and thus have nicely moving pictures (for reference, NSTC is 29.97 frames per second). This requires a bandwidth of 6 MHz and can be done at frequencies starting at 430 MHz in different amateur bands.

People also make use of NTSC and PAL modes. [Wikipedia has a few frequencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amateur_television).

Longer waves with lower frequencies don't offer enough bandwidth for "nice" video.

Comment: I'm working on a (live) FPV system that will function under fresh water. I beleive this would need a lower frequency so that the signal is not absorbed, but high enough to reasonably remotely control a craft. How low can you go for an image that is intelligible enough at as low as, say, one FPS?